# How to configure network adapter settings for same local network?

Tags: 14.04, networking, dhcp, lan, tftp

How to configure network adapter settings to set PC within same LAN with ATA box, which default ip is 192.168.15.1? Also how to setup TFTP server and DHCP server with OPTION 66 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Please describe what you have tried and what succeeded and what failed, and update with output from failed commands. Also ask only one question at the time.

Comment: I did it on Windows only using default system tools.

Comment: Is there handy GUI for that which allow set required setting in convenient way?